# "Error: Can't open display" with ubuntu bash and Xming

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I failed to open Xdisplay from ubuntu bash (opened in command prompt from Win11).

Setup:

1. Launch XLaunch with all default options
2. In command prompt, enter `bash` (Ubuntu)
3. Maybe relevant configs: In "/etc/ssh/sshd_config", `X11Forwarding yes` and `X11UseLocalhost yes`. In "/etc/ssh/ssh_config", `ForwardX11 yes` and `ForwardX11Trusted yes`.
4. Opening `xeyes` straight from Xming works just fine.
5. `DISPLAY=172.17.112.1:0.0; xeyes` will hang for a couple of minutes and then gives `Error: Can't open display:`. Any other `DISPLAY` I've tried (such as `127.0.0.1:0.0`, `localhost:0.0`) instantly gives the error message. Similarly, `gvim` or `matplotlib` from python scripts fail as well.

Ideally after this is resolved, I can use Xdisplay from `ssh` sessions (opened from `bash`) as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not an `if-then-else` programming problem usual for StackOverflow. Delete here and post to one of https://askubuntu.com , https://unix.stackexchange.com or (less likely) [su]. Please read their help to determine if your question is suitable there . Good luck.